# .DataManagerAppPreferenceActivity of defy in devices others

Tags: android

What's Intent I can make my app open Settings for enabled and disabled Data Package?

I try `ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS` but I'm wrong, because don't make the that I want.

I need just enabled and disabled data package...

The mobile that I use is motorola defy, and the Intent that I find that make the that I want is: `com.motorola.blur.datamanager.app.DataManagerAppPreferenceActivity`. But I need of native Intent of Android, because my app will run in device others.